# Estimating the alternating sum $\sum_{j \ge 1} (-1)^j e^{-j^2} j^k$

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, hypergeometric-functions, binomial-distribution

I have been trying to get a lower bound on the following alternating sum but without much success:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^T (-1)^j e^{-j^2} j^k .
$$
For small values of $k$, this is easy because the first term dominates the remaining terms.

For an upper bound, I can get an estimate using the gamma function by ignoring the sign change.  (Basically this reduces to estimating the moments of some Gaussian distribution.)

In general, what I want to estimate are summations of the form

$$
2^{-n} \sum_{j>0} \binom{n}{n/2 + jM} (-1)^j (jM)^k .
$$

(It may be useful to think of $M = C\sqrt{n}$ and $k = 1$ at first, but my goal is to understand the sum for other values of $M$ and $k$ in general.)

Is there any general method for estimating this kind of alternating sums?  Thanks.

Comment: Since $e^{-j^2}j^k$ is decreasing eventually, we're in the situation of the Leibniz criterion and obtain bounds from this (though perhaps not of the kind you were hoping for).

Comment: Use Abel’s bound and Abel Summation By Parts and then $\sum_{j=1}^k j^k$ related to Bernoulli numbers https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/abel%27s%2520theorem.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiJraSM0v7rAhX2UhUIHURtBUsQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1yG-GsEIxF7hCtcVMN_XfN

Comment: Let $(a_n)_{n\in N^*}$  be a sequence of Real or Complex numbers and $\varphi$ a Real or Complex function of class $C^1$.Let $A(x) = \sum_{1\le n \le x}{a_n}.$, then for all $x$ Real ,$\sum_{1\le n\le x}a_n\varphi(n)=A(x)\varphi(x)-\int_1^xA(u)\varphi'(u)\,\mathrm du$

Comment: Take $a_j=j^k$ and $\varphi(j)=(-1)^j e^{-j^2}$

Comment: I think you Can find an approximation formula of your sum by using  Abraham de Moivre formula for $\log n!$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Can you please explain a bit more on how to use de Moivre's formula for $\log n!$ to approximate the sum?